# How to get maven version number inside POM

Tags: java, maven

I need to get maven version number (e.g. 3.0.5, 3.1.0) from inside pom.xml file I need it to be able to add correct dependencies for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Version 3.1.0 requires the libraries at the same version, same for 3.0.5.
I would assume that there has to be something like `${maven.version}` in poms but I couldn't find it.

EDIT:
I need the project to work in both maven 3.0 and 3.1 so I can't do it statically it has to get the version of currently running maven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to define a property like this:

```
<properties>
  <maven.version>3.0.3</maven.version>
</properties>
```

and define the dependencies with such property within your pom file.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

or

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

or for the plugin-api like the following:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

For the maven-model it does not really matter if you are using 3.0.1 or 3.0.5 or 3.1 cause the model (pom.xml) hasn't been changed. For the plugin-api you can use 3.0.5 and get it running in Maven 3.1 as well. BTW: The above things are from a plugin which works under Maven 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: Unfortunately I use `RepositorySystemSession` in my plugin which was moved to a different package and to support both 3.0 and 3.1 the only solution I see is to use different dependencies for each of those.

Comment: It hasn't moved it has been solved different. You have to go an other way like in the following plugin [iterator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin). Take a look into the code there is a solution to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll find the solution in the plugin you mentionded

Answer (score 0):

You can add it yourself via a `settings.xml` file.

`${settings.mvn.version}` would refer to:

```
<settings>
  <mvn>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  <mvn>
</settings>
```

Or add `{$mvn.version}` directly in the `pom.xml`, by using:

```
<project>
...
  <properties>
     <mvn.version>3.1.0</mvn.version>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

Comment: I added an edit with better explanation, basically I need this version to by dynamically provided depending on maven version being executed.

Comment: I would never recommend to add a property like this into the setting.xml file, cause if someone else has a different settings.xml or has not defined any property your project couldn't be compiled etc.